# How to increase WordPress website backend speed

Tags: wordpress, performance, backend

I have created a test on the website where students come and register their accounts, right now there are 300+ users with customer user role, so my WordPress dashboard(backend) is loading too much and I am unable to edit anything, can anyone please help me with the solution how to increase the website backend speed

Answer (score 0):

This could be caused by a lot of things. A huge number of plugins or heavy plugins, an hosting service that is not powerful enough for this type of site, old php versions, low Wordpress memory limit.

Maybe you can contact your hosting provider to see if they can help.

Some resources you might find helpul:

[Slow WordPress Admin? Why It Happens, Plus How to Fix It](https://wp-rocket.me/blog/how-to-fix-slow-wordpress-admin/)

[The Ultimate Guide to Boost WordPress Speed & Performance](https://www.wpbeginner.com/wordpress-performance-speed/)